# Running Specific TestNG Groups from Maven

Tags: maven, testng

I have 2 groups of test cases as mentioend below.

```
@Test(groups="one", dataProvider = "TestData")
public void firstTest(String data){
   //Code
}

@Test(groups="one", dataProvider = "TestData")
public void secondTest(String data){
   //Code
}

@Test(groups="two", dataProvider = "TestData")
public void thirdTest(String data){
   //Code
}
```

Below is the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Test-Automation" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" verbose="1">
    <test name="Suite Test" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" verbose="1">
        <listeners>
             <listener class-name="GroupByInstanceEnabler"></listener>
        </listeners>

        <classes>
            <class name="SampleTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="firstTest"/>
                    <include name="secondTest"/>
                    <include name="thirdTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Below is the pom.xml build details.

```
 <build>
        <finalName>Automation</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <parallel>method</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My Question:

Using Maven, how do I run the group "one" and group "two" separately.

I tried "mvn test -Dgroups=two" but it only runs as normal(all tests).

Note: I use 2 different profiles to run the group "one" twice with different values. This is the reason you see profile configuration in the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of a beanshell expression for getting this done.

You first add a beanshell expression as below to your suite xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[whatGroup = System.getProperty("groupToRun");
                groups.containsKey(whatGroup);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="organized.chaos.GroupsPlayGround" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

This way you can make use of the suite xml from your IDE and still choose which groups to be executed. You can enrich this beanshell to run everything by default if no value is provided via the JVM argument `-DgroupToRun=one`

For more information on beanshell execution refer:

1. Official TestNG documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell)
2. My blog post [link](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/)

Comment: It works great. Please do something to have your blog listed in the top of google search results :D :)

Comment: @krishnan, can you help me with my question of same topic here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194956/no-engine-found-for-language-beanshell-while-running-testng-with-groups) please.?

Answer (score 0):

I got an error - Undefined argument: whatGroup  : at Line: 2 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``whatGroup = System.getProperty("groupToRun");