# No engine found for language: beanshell while running TestNG with groups

Tags: selenium, maven, testng

I followed this link [Running Specific TestNG Groups from Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404514/running-specific-testng-groups-from-maven) and i am having the similar setup of TestNG project. When i run the maven command with `-Dgroups` option, i get the below error. What is wrong with my setup. I am using `testng version 7.0.0`. Any help on this please.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project SeleniumTestNGProject: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /opt/TestProjects/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] No engine found for language: beanshell. Please check your dependencies and have a look at https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/Supported-script-engines
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] No engine found for language: beanshell. Please check your dependencies and have a look at https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/Supported-script-engines
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
```

My testng xml file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="Utilities.CustomTestListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="RegressionTests">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                    <![CDATA[whatGroup = System.getProperty("groups");
                    groups.containsKey(whatGroup);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.test_githubLoginTests"/>
            <class name="Tests.test_githubPricingTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Update:**

After adding the `org.apache-extras.beanshell` dependency in the pom file, ran again and got another error. please help on this.

```
[ERROR] Please refer to /opt/TestProjects/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
```

Comment: any help on this please?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this to your `dependencies` section:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache-extras.beanshell</groupId>
    <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
    <version>2.0b6</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are also [some alternative ways](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell#maven) to add beanshell processor.

Comment: i have tried as you said. added the dependency on my pom and ran. i dont see that error. But seeing some different error. could you please help on this. Updated the question with the current error.

Comment: I think you should rise a new question. I am not sure if solving this new and all possible following issues can be effectively done with a single question on SO.